# How to set the size of the range of historical data in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Tell me please one moment.
How to set the size of the calculated range of historical data in Pine?
For example, you want the function to be calculated from a certain candle (without sliding).
Fot example,

(open + close) / open

for the last 50 candles. Then a new bar appears for the last 51, for the last 52, and so on.
Mathematically it:

(open[i] + close[i]) / open[i] ->

(open[i+1] + close [i+1]) / open[i+1] ->

(open[i+2] + close [i+2]) / open[i+2] ->

(open[i+..n] + close [i+..n]) / open[i+..n]

I found two solutions, but it both do not work.

1. set the candle using
   *timestamp*
   and compare it with
   *if*
   using
   *time*.
   Example:

a= timestamp(...)

b= time > a ? (function) : na

Doesn't work, returns null value of the function.
Through the
*for*
loop, the same thing - a null value. Although the size of the counter is set in this way, but the function does not count.

2. max_bars_back
   I thought it can be set the number of bars that variables can use, but it does not work either through the *indicator*
   or as a separate function for the variable. Still counts as if no batch size has been set.

Please tell me how to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `timestamp` as a condition and do your calculations only whenever you are in the correct time window.

You also don't need a for loop. Just use a `var` variable.

Below example will start its calculations starting from 01 Aug 2022.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

in_time_start = input.time(timestamp("01 Aug 2022 00:00 +0000"), "Start Time")
in_time_end = input.time(timestamp("31 Dec 2031 00:00 +0000"), "End Time")

time_in_window = (time >= in_time_start and time <= in_time_end)

var float your_variable = 0.0

your_variable := time_in_window ? ((open + close) / open) : your_variable

plot(your_variable)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u, buddy! It works! Please tell me more how calculate this function in reverse order (from right to left)? For example: (open[50] + close[50]) / open[50]  -> (open [49] + close[49]) / open[49] -> etc.   The calculation of a function begins with a last bar in a chart - how does it do?

Comment: You need a for loop for that.